# Webpack 4: Production mode fails for React Library

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I'm trying to build my react library however it fails on `mode: production`. When I import my library to another application I get the following message:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property props of #<TWithProps> which has only a getter`.

Followed by:

`The above error occurred in the <_class3> component`

The problem is that it does seem to bundle up my library, however when importing the bundled libary, I get the 2 errors above. **Additionally** This does not happen in development mode.

I tried following many guides, however they all lead to the same result. My first assumption is that it's likely due to my minimizer plugin (I've tried both `UglifyPlugin` and `TerserPlugin`) however that is not the case. I've also read on webpack's documentation that it should use the minimizing plugin if given one. However it doesn't seem like it?

This is my webpack

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    index: [
      'babel-polyfill',
      './src/index.js',
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: srcBuild,
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    libraryExport: 'default',
  },
  optimization: {
    noEmitOnErrors: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        sourceMap: true,
        terserOptions: {
          mangle: false,
          compress: {
            reduce_funcs: false,
            reduce_vars: false,
            keep_classnames: true,
            keep_fnames: true,
            keep_fargs: true,
            pure_getters: true,
          },
        },
      }),
   ],
}
```

I'm expecting my library to run just fine as it does in `mode: development`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding this plugin

```
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

May I ask how are you consuming your library from the other application? You have `libraryTarget: 'commonjs'` in your config. If you don't know how your clients will consume your library, the suggested option is to set the export to [umd](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) by setting `libraryTarget: 'umd'`.

This should allow you to use ES6 `import` or just `require` it, webpack or the other app's bundler will take care of resolving them.

Comment: Hey I'm doing 
```
import MyLibrary from 'MyLibrary':
const { myComponent1, myComponent2 } = MyLibary;
```

This is working just fine in development mode